# Do excavators use electronic joystick and solenoid valves for direction control?

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, hydraulics

I studying how flow control happens in excavators. I came to know that the low pressure pilot line is used to control the high pressure hydraulic flow control valve (pilot operated direction control valve). I am confused about whether the low pressure line use solenoid valve or hydraulic valves. Because when I searched on internet for "Excavator joystick" few results shows joystick like image 1.
[image: Excavator Joystick]

It have few wires there. Any references to study excavator hydraulic system in detail.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that excavators of both kinds can't exist?

Comment: how do you know that the joysticks in the picture are not hydraulic?

Comment: Instead of pictures of the levers, check out the circuit diagrams then you will understand how things are connected.

Answer (score 1):

it depends,

older excavators (especially those with the 4 floor-mounted levers) will have those levers directly control the main hydraulic valves.

Building on that valve block for the 4 lever arrangement you can use a pilot hydraulic system that uses a lower pressure to actuate those main valves.

[image]

In the picture you shared the electronic wires are there for the buttons on the joystick. The large base is where the pilot control valves are, you can just see the blue protective caps used in shipping.

In some hydraulic equipment the controls are electronic, where the lever/button powers a solenoid which actuates the valve. This type of control is common when there is a second set of controls at the business end of the boom or there is a remote control.

Hybrid systems are also possible where a electronic switch controls a valve which changes what gets controlled by the lever/joystick.